# what does "be finished" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Englishtown](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY2OSZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY2OSZlZD0yMDE0LTEyLTAxVDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4)

> We're generally finished by 12.30..

I guess the above context means:

> We're generally finished with our work by 12.30

am I right?

I know I can say, "I am finished with my work by 11." But is it grammatical if I say "I am finished by 11."?

Comment: It can mean anything you want the other party to understand.  As you omit words like "with my work", the sentence opens for interpretation, of course. "Seeing the stock price plunge he shouted, 'I am finished!', and jumped out of the window."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We're generally finished by 12.30..

This could mean so many things. It could mean they finish their work by 12:30, or they would finish their lunch by 12:30 and so forth. Whatever the speaker wishes to convey through the sentence will be conveyed to the listener if he knows what the speaker is talking about. For example, you're talking to your sisters and you're talking about cooking. If one of them says _"We're generally finished by 12.30.." implies that they finish cooking by 12:30.
It all depends on the context in which these words are said. It generally means that :

> Whatever it is that 'they' are doing (or will do) will be completed by 12:30.

It is grammatically correct, but very vague.